# Does all traffic for jira software server get routed through atlassian first?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, self-hosting, oauth-1.0a

I'm trying to build an app that uses Jira Software Server data. On Jira Sass Oauth is simple enough, but after creating an SSL cert and configuring a localhost jira instance for development, I can't get any proper responses from my own server, for the older Oauth 1.0a flow, and all the documentation seems to reference https://jira.yourdomain.com. Is there some DNS that all self-hosted servers are routed through from Atlassian? I realize this self-hosted product is being slowly depreciated, but this new feature I want to provide for a client will require this connection since they are using this version of the software. Any insight would be useful since Atlassian Docs are so very outdated/not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

No, Jira Software on premise does not route traffic through Atlassian cloud.

There are lots of offline Jira instances.

Here is some documentation about oauth with Jira Server/Datacenter:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/oauth-troubleshooting-guide-719095274.html